# I don't enter in the hook "ActionProductCreate"

Tags: prestashop, hook, prestashop-1.7

I am doing a module on prestashop 1.7, what I want to do is more simple: add a line in a SQL table when a product is created. So I use the following hook:

```
public function hookActionProductCreate($params) {}
```

I put this code there in the hook but nothing happens on the side of my table, no added line:

```
public function hookActionProductCreate($params) {

    //Full name of my table : ps_mtp_product_dpt 

    Db::getInstance()->insert('mtp_product_dpt', array(
        'id_product' => 5,
        'id_departement' => 25,
    ));

}
```

Thank's you for you'r help

Comment: There is no hook `actionProductCreate`. Use `actionProductAdd`. Also make sure you register your hook.

Comment: @TheDrot Thanks for you'r response, i try with actionProductAdd but this doesn't work too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution, you just have to use this hook :

```
hookActionObjectProductAddAfter
```

Bye